# Avoiding jams in telescopic tracks

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to design a small metal telescopic track (6cm x 2cm when extended) where small objects may be arbitrarily positioned inside:

[image]

In the above example, the green block jams the tracks as the bottom cannot move upward. Does anyone know of a better design such that the tracks won't be jammed? I've thought about putting a sleeve on the inside, but if it was 6cm long and covers the entire extended length, it'd overhang when retracted.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few basic solutions you could try:

- Fist, you could put a pin or bump sticking out from the center of the inside channel so that before the channel bumps the edge of the green block (wedging it) the pin bumps the center of the green block (un-wedging it.)
- You could try making the inside of the track something smooth so the green block is less likely to get wedged. For example a thin layer of smooth plastic on the inside of the bigger channel would help the block slide more easily.
- You could install an accordion-folding guard that keeps objects away from the sides of the large channel when the small channel is extended. It would require you to make the large channel a little longer, but not twice as long like you would have to do with your original solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add a third track that fits inside the moving track, but is fixed to the outer track. That way, objects are always moving from a narrow track to a wider track, regardless of the position of the moving track.

Or just make the outer track the one that moves in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you beveled the edges of the end of the inner track so that they form a ramp rather than a square shoulder that would help a lot.

Alternatively, if the two tracks are not a very close fit and the objects in question could jam in the gap some sort of flexible baffle may help. In both cases the idea is to create a smooth ramp transition between the two rail elements so there are no sharp corners for things to snag on.

Similarly having non-parallel sides (some approximation of a 'V' section) is also likely to help.

Comment: Wouldn't bevels just increase the tendency to wedge the object in the track, rather than pushing it along?